# Filtering binding source

Tags: vb.net

This should be easy but I am having a headbanging of a time trying to get this to work! I have done a search and tried all most EVERY SINGLE ONE. Nothing works. I have a datagrid with a binding source. A user will type text into a textbox and the grid is SUPPOSED to change to only show records that contain what user typed in the name. Simple right? NOPE! Not for me! What am I doing wrong? Code below.

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click
    Dim Found As Boolean = False
    Dim StringToSearch As String = ""
    Dim ValueToSearchFor As String = "%" & SearchTextBox.Text.Trim.ToLower & "%"
    Dim CurrentRowIndex As Integer = 0

    Try

        If ReferencesGrid.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            CurrentRowIndex = 0
        Else
            CurrentRowIndex = ReferencesGrid.CurrentRow.Index + 1
        End If
        If CurrentRowIndex > ReferencesGrid.Rows.Count Then
            CurrentRowIndex = ReferencesGrid.Rows.Count - 1
        End If

        If ReferencesGrid.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For Each gRow As DataGridViewRow In ReferencesGrid.Rows
                StringToSearch = gRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString.Trim.ToLower
                If InStr(1, StringToSearch, LCase(Trim(SearchTextBox.Text)), vbTextCompare) Then
                    TrainingItemBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("Name LIKE '{0}'", ValueToSearchFor)

                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: `If InStr(1, StringToSearch, LCase(Trim(SearchTextBox.Text)), vbTextCompare) Then` In the first place, InStr returns an Integer not a Boolean so I don't see how it can be used in an If statement. In the second place, is a vb6 method and the .net IndexOf will serve you much better.

Answer (score 2):

You should get rid of pretty much all that code.  If you want to filter the data then just filter the data.  There's no conditional statements required and loops required.  Just set the `Filter` property and any records that don't match the filter will be hidden:

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click
    TrainingItemBindingSource.Filter = $"Name LIKE '%{SearchTextBox.Text.Trim()}%'"
End Sub
```

As you can see, it is simple.  I've no real idea what you were actually trying to achieve with the rest of that code.  That will exclude any records where the `Name` column does not contain the search text.

Note that there is no need to try to force case-insensitivity by using `ToLower` or the like.  Just like in real SQL, comparisons done this way in a `DataTable` are case-insensitive by default.  You have to explicitly set the `CaseSensitive` property of the `DataTable` or its parent `DataSet` to `True` to make such comparisons case-sensitive.

I should also point out that the ability to filter is predicated on the data source implementing certain interfaces.  If the data source is a `DataTable` then you have those interfaces for free.  If you have actually bound to something else, e.g. a `List(Of T)`, then you won't be able to filter this way because the required members do not exist.